# Menu Detecting taps far away from its icon

Tags: android, android-menu

Below are two pics of my app, the first showing the total area where you can click in order to activate the menu; the second  being the active popupMenu. I think the reason it acts this way is android:scaleType.

Is there another way I can get the icon to rest on the VCenter, HRightedge? I only want to activate the menu when the icon is tapped as well (but I think the icon i just scaled to fit all the space at the moment. Any ideas?

Here's the menu Java:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
            MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            popup.show();
        }

public boolean onMenuItemClick(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.demographics:
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(this, demoPanel.class);
            intent.putExtra("email", db.getUserDetails().get(db.KEY_EMAIL));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.settings:
            Log.v("v", "settings clicked");
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

And here's the XML:

```
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/rememberTableRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/rememberTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rememberDetails" android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/rememberCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="showPopup"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"/>

    </TableRow>
```

[image: Unselected]

[image: Selected]

Comment: Get rid of the `layout:weight`.

Comment: Just removed the weight for the imageview, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the layout weight to the CheckBox (so it can be selected in a big area, rather than just over itself.

```
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/rememberTableRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/rememberTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/rememberDetails" android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/rememberCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="showPopup"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"

            android:src="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"/>

    </TableRow>
```

Not an ideal solution, but it'll do for now.